# How can i store each cell from db in array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-workbench

I am looking for a way to access each row individually. I want to add these as options in a `<select>` tag and that's why i need each individually.

I was thinking of using the `$data` variable but when i put `$data['id'][1]` it would just show the 2nd character. When i used `$d[1]` it would give me a fatal error.

This is my code:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=liamed", "root", "");
      $query = "select * from users";
      $d = $pdo->query($query);
      foreach ($d as $data){

    ?>

    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $data['id'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['nume'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['prenume'];?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php }
  ?>
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: And what is wrong with provided code?

Comment: You state `$data['id'][1]` but your code uses `$data['id']` which should work.